# How to implement syntax highlighting using sed command in te gnome-terminal?

Tags: regex, linux, shell, sed, terminal

I want to highlight function names of a C program using the sed command on the linux terminal.

I am able to do it using tput to color the function name. For which I have provided the code below. (first line)

I am not able to do the coloring if I use printf/echo/command substitution to color the output of the terminal.  (second line of code). I guess this is because I am not able to reference the strings with \1 and \2. When using this it shows some other characters instead of the function names.

The regular expression I have used reads that, the first character of function name can be an alphabet or an underscore and the second character can be alphanumeric and underscore and the third character should be an open parenthesis. I want to reference the Regex by using \1 \2 and \3 and colour everything except \3. This is the idea I have come up with.

My question is, is there any other way to not color the open parenthesis or a way to use the printf and color the function name.

`sed -E "s,([a-zA-Z_])([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\(),$(tput setaf 1)\1\2$(tput sgr0)\3," Sample.c`

`sed -E "s,([a-zA-Z_])([a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\(),$(printf "\033[0;36m\1\2\033[0m\3")," Sample.c`

Sample .c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int array[100], maximum, size, c, location = 1;
  printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  printf("Enter %d integers\n", size);
  for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
  return 0;
}
```

Expected result -> main, printf, scanf should be coloured in Sample.c.

Answer (score 0):

The tput is clever however the backtracking will not resolve for an embedded printf because it's inside the subshell and so printf won't work.

There is a bashism which may work for you in the `var=$'ansi-ized content'` syntax. Three capture groups didn't seem necc. so omitted:

```
BEGC=$'\033[0;36m' ENDC=$'\033[0m'; \
sed -E "s,([a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*)(\(),${BEGC}\1${ENDC}\2," Sample.c
```

However, there's another more fundamental issue in that nested functions will not be highlighted. Notice in the updated Sample.c here that the fictitious "getSize()" function will not be highlighted:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int array[100], maximum, size, c, location = 1;
  printf("Enter the number of elements in array\n");
  scanf("%d", &size);
  printf("Enter %d integers\n", getSize(size));
  for (c = 0; c < size; c++)
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);
  return 0;
}
```

A simple regex will not work as there is a recursion requirement. Probably awk can do it since it has a while loop and functions (gensub() maybe?)